# Change image URL upon select event

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am trying to change an image when an option in the select list is selected. I can't figure out that I'm missing.

**HTML**

```
<img class="prime" src="images/image_small.jpg">
    <form>
        Select image size:
        <select onchange="biggieSmalls()">
            <option value="small">Small</option>
            <option value="medium">Medium</option>
            <option value="large">Large</option>
        </select>
    </form>
    <p id="optimus"></p>
```

**JS**

```
function biggieSmalls() {
    image = document.querySelector(".prime").value;
    if (image == "small") {    
        document.getElementById('optimus') = "<img src =    'images/image_small.jpg'>";
    }
  
    if (image == "medium"){ 
        document.getElementById('optimus') = "<img src = 'images/image_medium.jpg'>";
    } 

    if (image == "large)" {
        document.getElementById('optimus') = "<img src = 'images/image_large.jpg'>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Included event to `biggieSmalls(event)`
and then fixed a few syntax errors

And then you can use `event.target.value` to obtain the `select`'s seletecd value. Use `.innerHTML` to change the content inside a `<p>`

```
function biggieSmalls(event) {
    var image = event.target.value;
    if (image == "small") {
        document.getElementById('optimus').innerHTML = "<img src = 'images/image_small.jpg'>";
    }
    if (image == "medium") {
        document.getElementById('optimus').innerHTML = "<img src = 'images/image_medium.jpg'>";
    }
    if (image == "large") {
        document.getElementById('optimus').innerHTML = "<img src = 'images/image_large.jpg'>";
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lkx0zr16/2/

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to update the src value based on the value of the select, in that case you can use a simple regex to do it like

```js
function biggieSmalls(value) {
  var img = document.querySelector(".prime");
  img.src = img.src.replace(/_(small|medium|large)(?=\.)/, '_' + value)
}
```

```html
<p id="temp"></p>
<img class="prime" src="images/image_small.jpg">
<form>
  Select image size:
  <select onchange="biggieSmalls(this.value)">
    <option value="small">Small</option>
    <option value="medium">Medium</option>
    <option value="large">Large</option>
  </select>
</form>
<p id="optimus"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are getting the value of select and based on that value, you want to show the image inside the `<p id="optimus"></p>`

```js
function biggieSmalls() {
  // I change selector to `select`
  image = document.querySelector("select").value;
  
  // you can also refactor your multiple if statements to a switch statement or if elseif
  if (image == "small") {
    // added `.innerHTML`  
    document.getElementById('optimus').innerHTML = "<img src =    'images/image_small.jpg'>";
  }

  if (image == "medium") {
    document.getElementById('optimus').innerHTML = "<img src = 'images/image_medium.jpg'>";

  }

  if (image == "large") {
    document.getElementById('optimus').innerHTML = "<img src = 'images/image_large.jpg'>";

  }

}
```

```html
<img class="prime" src="images/image_small.jpg">
<form>
  Select image size:
  <select onchange="biggieSmalls()">
    <option value="small">Small</option>
    <option value="medium">Medium</option>
    <option value="large">Large</option>
  </select>
</form>
<p id="optimus"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to change the `background` of the `p` element ,But

```
document.getElementById('optimus') = "<img src = ....
```

is incorrect.

you have to use `backgroundImage` property of `style` attribute.

Also there is a typo

```
 if (image == "large)" {
                    ^^ Note Here
        }
```

Hope this snippet will serve your purpose

HTML

```
<select onchange="biggieSmalls(this)">
<option value="small">Small</option>
<option value="medium">Medium</option>
<option value="large">Large</option>
</select>
</form>
<p id="optimus"></p>
```

CSS

```
p{

  height:200px;
  width:200px;
}
```

JS

```
   // Using some dummy Images for demo
 function biggieSmalls(val) {
        var image = document.querySelector(".prime").value; // Not sure why you used this line
        var getValue = val.value;
        if (getValue == "small") {
         document.getElementById('optimus').style.backgroundImage= 

"url('http://www.orderofinterbeing.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/light-forest.jpg')"; 
         }

        else if (getValue === "medium"){
        document.getElementById('optimus').style.backgroundImage= 

"url('http://assets.worldwildlife.org/photos/946/images/story_full_width/forests-why-matter_63516847.jpg?1345534028')"; 
        } 

        else if (getValue == "large") {
         document.getElementById('optimus').style.backgroundImage= 

"url('http://freebigpictures.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/coniferous-forest.jpg')"; 
        }
        }
```

[WORKING EXAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/m7vb3eoj/9/)